# Result set in multiple jLabel using array

Tags: java, sql-server

How can I create a multiple jLabel using the result set from database column?
I spent almost 2 days trying to solve but unfortunately i still didn't get it correct. please help me.

Here's my codes:

```
String[] arr = null;
    try{
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Position";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String s1 = rs.getString("PositionName");
            arr = s1.split("\n");
            int v = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
               JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[i];
               labels[i] = new JLabel();
               labels[i].setBounds(50,v,80,20);
               labels[i].setText(arr[i]);
                jPanel3.add(labels[i]);
                v+=40;
              System.out.println(arr[i]);
           }
             jPanel3.repaint(); 
        }
```

I want a result something like this, (in a jLabel)

```
President

Vice-President

Secretary
```

if i make int i = 0 the output is "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0"
if i make it int i = 1, there's no error but not created jLabel at all.

Comment: Your array should be initialized outside the "while" loop... but since you can't tell its size in advance, I recommend an ArrayList instead of array. So just before the "while" loop you can define "ArrayList<JLabel> labels=new ArrayList<>()" and then in teach iteration you can add a label.

Answer (score 0):

**initialize JLabel array outside the for-loop**

```
 JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){                   
                   labels[i] = new JLabel();
                   labels[i].setBounds(50,v,80,20);
                   labels[i].setText(arr[i]);
                    jPanel3.add(labels[i]);
                    v+=40;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When `i` == 0, then

JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[i];

creates an array which can't hold anything since it's size is 0. So then

```
labels[i] = new JLabel();
```

attempts to set the element at index 0 which causes the exception.

The code is attempting to do too much which can make it difficult to find bugs.  Try separating the code into single responsibility methods such as:

```
List<String> getAvailablePositions() {
   // get the positions from the database
}
```

and

```
void addPositionLabels(List<String> availablePositions) {
   // add the positions to the JPanel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is the sample code **

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(300,300);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            int v = 50;
            JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                labels[i] = new JLabel();
                labels[i].setBounds(50,v,80,20);
                labels[i].setText("hi");
                panel.add(labels[i]);
                v+=40;
            }
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

**you will get the following result

```
     hi

     hi

     hi**
```

Comment: doesn't help at all sir